# Boolean Look up Tables - Bool Column or Simple Lookup?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

We need a table to store requests for a copy of a contract, let's say `contract_copy_requests`.

The user either made a request, or did not. The field is unlikely to ever toggle.

Which of these column options is "correct":

1. `profile_id, request date` (and only write ids that made a request in here)  OR
2. `profile_id, has_requested_copy, updated_date`

The latter is more complete and extensible, but the former is simpler and doesn't require either a nullable field or backfilling existing data with `false` for everyone since they haven't made the choice yet.

Is there any real reason to do #2? Btw, this is more of a generic question - I have had this use case come up about 3 times in the past month and I always lean toward #1 but wanted to validate it.

Comment: If we follow the KISS principle, the option #1 is better. However, option #2 could provide a more flexible solution if you anticipate there could be an *imminent change* in the logic. If the latter is not the case I would stick with option #1.

Comment: These two alternatives don't actually seem to be alternatives.  You say "backfilling existing data with false for everyone", but what is "everyone"?  Everyone who you have done business with? Everyone who exists on Earth, known to you and unknown to you?  Everyone who hypothetically might exist throughout the universe?  It seems like the only realistic alternative is not between two different tables, but between one table on one hand, and two tables on the other hand.

Comment: What happens if the client makes a second request?

Comment: @Belayer I am ignoring that scenario. No entry. Basically, if anyone ever cares, they want a copy of their contracts. The two alternatives are a second entry, removing the unique constraint, OR updating the request date, if we don't really care how many times they requested this. The direction from management is "we don't even need to store the choice, just send out a copy.", so I am taking the simplest approach here just because I know eventually they will ask for a report on how many people requested this, if we can send corrected documents, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is better.

It is smaller, and you lose no functionality: for example, it will be easy to get the users that didn't make a request:

```
... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM contract_copy_requests AS ccr
                      WHERE ccr.request.id = /* column from the outside */)
```